# R - Strange pie chart behavior in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a pie chart from a small data frame. At first everything worked well

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

c1 <- c(2,3)
c2 <- c("second","third")
c2 <- factor(c2, levels = c("first","second","third","fourth"))
c3 <- c(0.7,0.3)
cs <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)
ct <- data.table(cs)
colx <- c("blue","red")
midpoint <- cumsum(ct$c3) - ct$c3/2

keycols = c("c1")
setkeyv(ct,keycols)
ct



    c1   c2  c3
1:  2 second 0.7
2:  3  third 0.3

vysg <- ggplot(ct, aes(x=1,y=c3,fill=c2)) + 
          geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
          coord_polar(theta='y')+
          theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), 
            axis.text.y = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(color=colx,size=15,hjust=0))+ 

        scale_y_continuous(breaks = midpoint, labels = ct$c2)  + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=colx) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2.5))
vysg
```

[image]

The problems start when I need to add new rows to the dataframe(data.table) (the zero results for first and fourth)

```
ctlab <- data.table(levels(c2))
nlabs <- ctlab[!V1%in%ct$c2]
nlabs[, V1 := factor(V1,levels=c("first","second","third","fourth"))]
nct <- data.frame(c1=c(1,4),c2=nlabs[,V1],c3=0)
ct <- rbind(ct,nct)
colx <- c("green","blue","red","brown")
ct$c2 <- factor(ct$c2,levels=c("first","second","third","fourth"))
ct$c4 <- as.character(ct$c2)
keycols = c("c1")
setkeyv(ct, keycols)
ct

   c1     c2  c3     c4
1:  1  first 0.0  first
2:  2 second 0.7 second
3:  3  third 0.3  third
4:  4 fourth 0.0 fourth
```

The data.table looks ok but the chart is not

```
midpoint <- cumsum(ct$c3) - ct$c3/2
vysg <- ggplot(ct, aes(x=1,y=c3,fill=c2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
  coord_polar(theta='y') +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),  panel.grid  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(color=colx,size=15,hjust=0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = midpoint, labels = ct$c2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colx) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,2.5))
vysg

Warning message:
In `[[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, n, value = "first/fourth") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

[image]

After replacing c2 by c4 (string) in labels the warning does not appear but the chart is not ok

```
midpoint <- cumsum(ct$c3) - ct$c3/2
vysg <- ggplot(ct, aes(x=1,y=c3,fill=c2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),  panel.grid  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color=colx,size=15,hjust=0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = midpoint, labels = ct$c4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colx) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2.5))
vysg
```

[image]

I guess the problem is hidden in the factor (c2) but cannot find a way how to amend it. I explicitly set levels in both - the old data.frame and the new one.

Comment: Just don't make a pie chart. They're undeniably the worst charts ever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that 0° and 360° are the same angle and ggplot2 knows this. You'd see that if you only plotted this:

```
ggplot(ct, aes(x=1, y=c3, fill=c2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
  coord_polar(theta='y')
```

Thus, you need to do some preparation for the labels:

```
midpoint[midpoint == 1] <- 0
labs <- aggregate(ct$c2, list(midpoint), FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = "/"))
vysg<-ggplot(ct, aes(x=1, y=c3, fill=c2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
  coord_polar(theta='y')+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),  panel.grid  = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=colx,size=15,hjust=0))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=labs$Group.1, labels=labs$x)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colx)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2.5))
vysg
```

[image: resulting plot]

Different colors in the scale label are not possible (without editing at the grid graphics level). Maybe `scale_fill_manual(values=colx[as.integer(factor(midpoint))])` would suit your needs.

Finally, the obligatory advice: There is usually a much better option than a pie chart to illustrate such data.